# number of models changes incorrect after cpagination applylimit

Tags: yii

I'm trying to make models layout with pagination. pageSize is 8. Here is the code:

```
$count = Salon::model()->count($criteria);
$this->pages           = new CPagination($count);
$this->pages->pageSize = Yii::app()->params['catalogPageSize'];

echo 'count1: ' . count(Salon::model()->FindAll($criteria));
$this->pages->applyLimit($criteria);
echo 'count2: ' . count(Salon::model()->FindAll($criteria));
```

The output is:
count1: 9
count2: 7

Why is it so? I can't get no answer...

Comment: Could you tell us the value currentPage, itemCount, pageCount and limit of your CPagination object ?

Comment: Count = 9 (before applyLimit), limit (pagesize) = 8. What is "currentPage"? I don't use it. All my pagination part is almost 100% of reference from yii docs.

Comment: I'm talking about the CPagination's attribute, not what you observe outside of it.

Comment: I made a test: getCurrentPage: 0, getItemCount: 9, getPageCount: 2
getLimit: 8

Comment: Hum so everything seems fine in your CPagination object. Could you show us the logs of the executed requests (you may have to enable query logs)

Comment: I'm sorry, it took time to get debugfer work. Log is: system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `salons` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `salon_addresses` `addresses` ON (`addresses`.`salonId`=`t`.`id`) WHERE ((((t.active=:ycp0) AND (salonTypeId=:ycp1)) AND (addresses.cityId=:ycp2)) AND (addresses.districtId=:ycp4)). Bound with :ycp0='0', :ycp1='1', :ycp2='1', :ycp4='12')

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52674/discussion-between-darkheir-and-dmitri-malyshev)

Answer (score 0):

CPagination doesn't work correctly on complex queries which contain duplicates of objects. The result query with no limit returns 14 lines (9 objects with duplicates). I will try to implement pagination w/o CPagination.